# How to set minimum date to previous month 26

Tags: android

How to set minimum date to previous month 26. This is my code.

```
int difference = 0;
if (month == 1 || month == 3 || month == 5 || month == 7 || month == 8 || month == 10 || month == 12) {
    difference = 31;
} else if (month == 4 || month == 6 || month == 9 || month == 11) {
    difference = 30;
} else if (month == 2) {
    if (year % 4 == 0) {
        difference = 29;
    } else
        difference = 28;
}

int minDiffrence = 0;
if (day == 26) {
    minDiffrence = difference;
} else {
    minDiffrence = difference - (26 - day);
}

dpd.getDatePicker().setMinDate(System.currentTimeMillis() - 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 * minDiffrence);
```

Comment: At the top you say you want the 26th of the previous month, but your code example seems to be getting the last day of the month. Please clarify. Your Question is not clear.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

                    calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) - 1);
                    calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 26);

                    dpd.getDatePicker().setMinDate(calendar.getTimeInMillis());
```

Answer (score 0):

This code sample code is to cover **From Date = starting date of previous month** and **End date = current date of present month**. I think this code is helpful to you.

```
 datePicker = (DatePicker) findViewById(R.id.datePicker);

    calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.add(Calendar.MONTH, -1);
    calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
    datePicker.setMinDate(calendar.getTimeInMillis());
    datePicker.setMaxDate(new Date().getTime());
```